# How to print sequential data out of a Sequelize query with associations using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I'm trying to get a simple sequential output from a demo Node.js app and Sequelize, but I can't seem to wrap my head around promises and Bluebird and how those can help me. The output I'm after is this:

```
User: John Doe
    Project: "Acme Website": Sample project
    Project: "PMC Website": Sample project

    Total projects: 2

User: Jane Doe
    Project: "ABC Website": Sample project

    Total projects: 1

User: Jill Doe
    No projects

Total users: 3
```

I am not using Express. This is just a demo app to figure out all these things.

Here is my `User` model:

```
// models/user.js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.hasMany(models.Project);
  };
  return User;
};
```

Here is my `Project` model:

```
// models/project.js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Project = sequelize.define('Project', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {});
  Project.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Project.belongsTo(models.User);
  };
  return Project;
};
```

The code I've written doesn't work, obviously:

```
User.findAndCountAll().then((result) => {
  if (result.count > 0) {
    let users = result.rows;

    users.forEach((user, index, arr) => {
        console.log('User: ' + user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName + ' <' + user.email + '>' + '\n' );
        user.getProjects().then((projects) => {
          projects.forEach((project, index, arr) => {
            console.log('\tProject: "' + project.title + '": ' + project.description + '\n');
          });
        }).then((projects) => {
          console.log('\tTotal projects: xxx'); // xxx should be the count
        });
      }
    );

    console.log('Total users: ' + result.count);
  } else {
    console.log('No users');
  }
});
```

I know I need to use promises, but I can't figure out where or how. I saw some tutorials with callbacks and `setTimeout`s, but I think I should stay away from those, right?

I don't want to simply construct an array or object of values and then output that at the end, because it doesn't solve my problem of not being able to understand how promises work.

*Edit:* I am not sure if I'm asking the right questions, even. I am trying to understand async by trying out a sync example, but that's probably not the way to go about it. I suppose the answer lies in the fact that if I'm looking to use an async platform like JavaScript, I shouldn't be artificially imposing sync-like wait times. Instead, if we consider the example above, it's probably a better idea to run through the results and collect the data into an object and then output that. Alternatively the method suggested by @Priyank below (fixed and modified) would give me the exact output:

```
User.findAndCountAll({
  include:[
    Project
  ]
}).then(result => {    
  result.rows.forEach((user, index, arr) => {
      console.log('User: ' + user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName + ' <' + user.email + '>');

      user.Projects.forEach((project, index, arr) => {
          console.log('\tProject: "' + project.title + '": ' + project.description);
      });

      console.log('\n\tTotal projects: ' + user.Projects.length + '\n');
  });

  console.log('\nTotal users: ' + result.count + '\n');
}).finally(() => {
  process.exit();
});
```

While this does give me the expected output, I believe I have been trying to solve the wrong problem with JavaScript. Hence, I do not want to mark that answer as accepted, because there is no right answer to my wrong question.

Comment: `sequential` Do you want the requests to go out in serial rather than in parallel?

Comment: @CertainPerformance What exactly do you mean 'requests'? For the purposes of this example, the answer would probably be yes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with below code and check.

```
User.findAndCountAll({
    include:{
        model:model.project // your project model
    }
}).then( result => {    
    console.log( "result=====>",result);
    result.forEach((user, index, arr) => {
        console.log('User: ' + user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName + ' <' + user.email + '>' + '\n' );
        user.project.forEach((projects, index, arr) => {
            console.log('\tProject: "' + project.title + '": ' + project.description + '\n');
        });
    }
});
```

[Document](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html)

**Check your console and print data accordingly.**

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help. I was able to print each user in a sequence at the beginning, but my requirement is now complicated by the associations.

Comment: you will get  all the details of users as well as projects in the result.

Comment: This doesn't work, but I including the associations isn't what I am after. Including or calling getAssociation is irrelevant, as I still can't figure out how to display the count of each set of rows after all the rows have been displayed.

Comment: just add user.project.length for the count

Comment: You're jumping ahead and just "getting it done" with solutions I've already tried before, but that doesn't help me learn how to work with the promises returned by Sequelize/Bluebird. Understand that this isn't a project I need to finish. I need to learn.